# UITableView cells when selected nothing happened in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview

**I try this code on  IOS5 working fine but  when i try on IOS6 do nothing 
I'm not able to reproduce the problem...
Can any body help me it's drive me crazy....
**

```
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
     UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell.textLabel.text== @"Cairo") {

    //Cairo

    center.latitude=29.333983;
    center.longitude=30.453069;
    span.latitudeDelta=1.400686;
    span.longitudeDelta= 2.705383;
    region.center=center;
    region.span=span;
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

    }

    else if(cell.textLabel.text== @"Alexandria")
    {
    // Alexandria

    center.latitude=31.200092;
    center.longitude=29.918739;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.324794;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.676346;
    region.center=center;
    region.span=span;
    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not compare strings with ==, as it will compare the pointers, which may not be the same. On iOS 5 it could be, so it worked. You need to use isEqual: or isEqualToString:

```
if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cairo"]) { // do stuff
```

Also, it's generally a bad practice to assume things based on UI. You should have a model, and use indexPath to get the logical value.